# Typescript tsconfig not respecting noUnusedLocal rule

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a project using `typescript 3.6.3`.

In my root I have a `tsconfig.json` with `noUnusedLocals: true`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,

  },
  "include": ["*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*"]
}
```

I have a file in the same root directory containing `const unusedVar = '';`. When I run `npx tsc --project tsconfig.json` it does not throw an error during compilation.

If I add `sourceMap: true` to my tsconfig and compile, the source maps get added, so my config is being respected. But why does `noUnusedLocals` not work?

Comment: Works on play: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noUnusedLocals=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwBQEoBciBucYAmiA3gFCIWIQIDOUKiAvIgCwBMA3KQL5A What code did you compile?

Comment: Where is `const unusedVar = '';` declared? Are you sure it's a _local_ variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file with just

```
const unusedVar = '';
```

then it's expected the warning triggered: `noUnusedLocals` is a rule that triggers on unused *local* variables, while that variable you declared is global.

To make it local put it in a function or simply in an unnamed block `{ const unusedVar = ''; }`

Comment: Thanks for the help I was totally misunderstanding the rule. I switched to using ts's `noUnusedLocals` instead of eslint's `no-unused-variable` thinking they were similar.  I find the ts/tslint integration very confusing right now.